# reduce Facebook SDK size for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I integrated facebook SDK in my app, the problem is the size of the SDK (around 12mb), is there any way to decrease this size? i'm using facebook feed dialog only...

I tried to remove "Facebook SDK" document file (11+ MB) from the actual Facebook SDK folder, surprisingly i can still use facebook in my app, share items thru feed dialog HOWEVER, i'm getting around 70 warning :S

warning: (armv7) /Users/Desktop/iPhone App/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o) unable to open object filewarning: (armv7)

is there anyway to get rid of these warning OR i have no other option than going with the same facebook SDK size e.g. 12mb

I just tried running app on the simulator, it does not give me any warning however, on my both devices iPhone 4 & 5, it gives me around 70 warnings...

Comment: The size of the framework does not matter .... your app size will not increase due to the framework....

Comment: even if the facebook sdk was downloaded from facebook.developer website? i see my app folder show increase of 12mb?

Comment: I know i know ... do one thing integrate it with ur app and then see the size of the app .... try it

Comment: It added +30 MB in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing , integrate it with your app and then see the size of the app .... and you dont need to add the whole folder to it .... only the Facebook sdk , the rest are the samples from facebook out of which you can use any according to your requirement.

Hope this is what you require ...

Comment: i copied FacebookSDK.framework folder to my app's framework folder, as shown in the facebook "Get started" video, i see a 12mb increase in my app folder.. i even made an ipa file and it only reduces my app size from 50 mb to 46, help!!

Answer (score 0):

Along with just adding only the framework files...When your app is actually archived and a .ipa (iOS application) file is produced you will see a TREMENDOUS drop in file size.

For instance.

I have added

ZXing(barcode scanner)....which is 212mb alone
Parse SDK
Facebook SDK
iCarousel
10 view controllers
Objective-Zip

Even with all this in my application my .ipa is sitting at a little over 4mb. Which is pretty small by todays standards for an iOS app. Installed it was a 6.7mb

The easiest way to tell how bit it is would be to run on a device.

On your iOS device(maybe even the simulator) go to Settings > General > Usage and find it in the list. My bet is you'll be quite shocked as to how small the actual application is when its compiled.

So the main issue left is that your settings and the way you have it setup is the main issue...not the size. I would look into that instead.

Comment: i checked my app size using my device, settings > General > Usage, my app is showing 50 mb , whereas, without the facebookSDK.framework, its only 37mb

Comment: i copied FacebookSDK.framework folder to my app's framework folder, as shown in the facebook "Get started" video, i see a 12mb increase in my app folder.. i even made an ipa file and it only reduces my app size from 50 mb to 46, help!!

Comment: Ipa also includes information on how to install application. Install it all the way and check your actual memory size as mentioned in my reply above. One way you might cut down on size is to compile large tasks as a library..